# SQL case statement with condition adding two large int values

Tags: sql, int, case, bigint

I have a sql query that has a case statement. The case statement has a condition that adds two integer values and verifies their sum is smaller than the max integer value allowed by sql (rounded in the example for simplicity) beeefore assigning it back to another int type variable.
The issue is, in the WHEN statement where the two values are being added, since the sum value is larger than the sql max allowed integer, the whole statement throws a sql arithmetic exception. I am ASSUMING internally the sum value is placed in a temporary integer variable when adding the two integer values...
Eg,

```
Declare @int1 as Int =2147483598
Declare @int2 as Int =2147483598
Declare @int3 as Int =0
DECLARE @MaxIntValue INT = 2147483600

set @int3 = (CASE WHEN (@int1 < 2)
                    THEN @int1 
                  WHEN ((@int1 + @int2) < @MaxIntValue)
                    THEN @int1 + @int2
                  ELSE @int1
            END)
select @int3
```

I found a work around where if I change the type of one of the variables to a bigint instead
(i.e,

```
Declare @int1 as bigint =2147483598
```

)
the issue is resolved since I am again ASSUMING the datatype of the variable used to hold the sum value internally now changes to a bigint type as well. I would like to avoid this solution since in reality this query is part of a much bigger and complex stored procedure which involves multiple tables from where these values are procured.
Thank you.

Comment: So, what kind of answer are you looking for? You have a work-around.. What's wrong with it, exactly?

Comment: This case statement is actually a part of a big stored proc and is encapsulated inside a MERGE statement where fields   from two tables are merged and one of the fields is updated based on this CASE statement. Since the integer values I used in this example come directly from the tables I would have to change the datatype in the table which I don't think is the simplest solution.

Comment: why dont cast the variable to bigint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting to bigint

```
Declare @int1 as Int =2147483598
Declare @int2 as Int =2147483598
DECLARE @MaxIntValue BIGINT = 2147483600
                     ^^^^^^
set @int3 = (CASE WHEN (@int1 < 2)
                  THEN @int1 
                  WHEN ((CAST(@int1 AS bigint) +   
                         CAST(@int2 AS bigint)) < @MaxIntValue)
                  THEN @int1 + @int2
                  ELSE @int1
             END);
select @int3
```

Comment: Thank you Juan. Casting the variables resolved the issue. Just FYI, I didn't need to change @MAXIntValue variable type though, i.e., it seemed to have no effect eitherway. Thank you  for the full example as well.

Comment: Even when you say work, I rather be safe than sorry.  Maybe the engine is doing the cast for you behind doors.